# Find a specific value from a XML Converted C# object

Tags: c#, xml, object

I have deserialized an XML file. And the Serialize contract is auto generated. one of field it is converted to an object.

The XML contract:

```
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PrtryId"),typeof(string)]
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("BICFI"),typeof(string)]
 public object Item{
    get{ return this.itemField;}
    set{ this.itemField = value }
 }
```

The XML File

```
 <Pty>
     <PrtryId>
         <Id>Agent Code</Id>
     </PrtryId>
 </Pty>
```

Now I want to get this value, the code below is not working. The document here is the object that I have got from XML after convert to C# object.

```
 var FinalValue = document.SbcptOrdr.MltpOrdrDtls.InvstmtAcctDtls.AcctSvcr.Pty.Item.GetType().GetProperty("PrtryId")
```

The value I get from Immediate Console.
document.SbcptOrdr.MltplOrdrDtls.InvstmtAcctDtls.AcctSvcr.Pty.Item

```
Id: "Agent Code"
Issr: null
SchmeNm: null
idField: "Agent Code"
issrField: null
schmeNmField: null
```

So How can I get the Id value??????? Thanks

============

The problem is solved by using this

```
    var FinalValue = 
    document.SbcptOrdr.MltpOrdrDtls.InvstmtAcctDtls.AcctSvcr.Pty.Item as 
    ContributionV0
```

this ContributionV0 is a generic class in that data contract.

and I can get the value by 
        Finalvalue.Pty.Id

Comment: Why do you have lowercase pty and uppercase Pty?

Comment: @jdweng sorry, that is a typo.